# How can I update a dataclass in place?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Given two instances of the same dataclass, how can I update the first one in-place with values from the second one?

i.e.

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: str
    b: int

f1 = Foo("foo", 1)
f2 = Foo("bar", 2)

# Update in place, so that f1.a == f2.a, f1.b == f2.b and so on
```

Note: I do not want to simply set `f1 = f2`; I want to update `f1` in place.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dataclasses.fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) to loop through all the attributes and set them one by one.

```py
from dataclasses import fields

for f in fields(f2):
    setattr(f1, f.name, getattr(f2, f.name))
```